# How do I find first value in every last 3 months in Hive

Tags: sql, hive, partitioning

I have a table like below.

```
+-------+-------+--------------+---------------+
| Col_1 | Col_2 | Refresh_Date | Refresh_Value |
+-------+-------+--------------+---------------+
| AE    | A1    | 2019-12-01   |             1 |
| AE    | A1    | 2020-01-01   |             3 |
| AE    | A1    | 2020-02-01   |             5 |
| AE    | A1    | 2020-03-01   |             7 |
| AE    | A1    | 2020-04-01   |            12 |
| AE    | A1    | 2020-05-01   |            14 |
| AE    | A1    | 2020-06-01   |            11 |
| AE    | A1    | 2020-07-01   |            15 |
+-------+-------+--------------+---------------+
```

I need to get the first `Refresh_value` (based on `Refresh_date`) from last 3 months starting from the last date and there should be 2 additional columns (`Group` and `Refresh_Value_Min`) where 1st column will have the first value from every last 3 months and another column will have values which says in which group these dates fall into.

**Expected output**

```
+-------+-------+--------------+---------------+-------+-------------------+
| Col_1 | Col_2 | Refresh_Date | Refresh_Value | Group | Refresh_Value_Min |
+-------+-------+--------------+---------------+-------+-------------------+
| AE    | A1    | 2019-12-01   |             1 | Grp3  |                 1 |
| AE    | A1    | 2020-01-01   |             3 | Grp3  |                 1 |
| AE    | A1    | 2020-02-01   |             5 | Grp2  |                 5 |
| AE    | A1    | 2020-03-01   |             7 | Grp2  |                 5 |
| AE    | A1    | 2020-04-01   |            12 | Grp2  |                 5 |
| AE    | A1    | 2020-05-01   |            14 | Grp1  |                14 |
| AE    | A1    | 2020-06-01   |            11 | Grp1  |                14 |
| AE    | A1    | 2020-07-01   |            15 | Grp1  |                14 |
+-------+-------+--------------+---------------+-------+-------------------+
```

I tried the below code that will give the value of the 3rd last month in the current row, but I need the output as like above.

```
first_value(Refresh_Value) over (partition by col_1,col_2 order by Refresh_Date ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
```

Can someone help in this.

Please let me know if there are any questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me explain the approach (tiny details might differ):

1. Get last date in each row

```sql
with data_with_last_dt as (
  select Col_1, Col_2, Refresh_Date, Refresh_Value,
         max(Refresh_Date) over (partition by Col_1, Col_2) as Last_Date
    from target_table
),
```

2. Get the difference in months and divide it by 3 (integer division) -- you'll get the group number

```sql
data_with_group as (
  select Col_1, Col_2, Refresh_Date, Refresh_Value,
         cast(months_between(Last_Date, Refresh_Date) as int) / 3 as Group_Id
    from data_with_last_dt 
)
```

3. Find the first `Refresh_Value` within each group:

```sql
select Col_1, Col_2, Refresh_Date, Refresh_Value, Group_Id,
       min(Refresh_Value) over(partition by Col_1, Col_2, Group_Id order by Refresh_Date) as Refresh_Value_Min 
  from data_with_group
```

Comment: The `min` in point 3 is not working always. I used `first_value` function instead. But your overall approach is good and I am able to see the expected result. Accepting this answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

First find groups:

```
tbl1:
select col1, col2, refrech_date, refresh_value,
       cast((row_number() over (partition by col1, col2 order by refresh_date desc)/3 as int) as group
  from table
```

then find min value

```
tbl2:
select col1, col2, refrech_date, refresh_value, group
  from tbl1
 where refresh_date = min(refresh_date) over (partition by col1, col2, group)
```

then join min values

```
tbl3:
select t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.refrech_date, t1.refresh_value, t1.group, t2.refresh_value as refresh_value_min
  from tbl1 t1
  join tbl2 t2
    on(t1.col1 = t2.col1 and t1.col2 = t2.col2 and t1.group = t2.group)
```